# highchart: "grouped categories" mutil categorie show not beautiful

Tags: highcharts

I create mutil chart (type=bar) using grouped_categories.
But label for group show not beautiful.
I using .reflow() or render(), but not work.
Tks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5A52.png

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug reported on `grouped_categories` plugin repository:

- https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/issues/100
- https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/issues/28

The workaround is to manually position the first label:

```
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            x: -4,
            y: 7
        },
        categories: [...]
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gejbs6fr/